# Cybertruck Monocoque body design

Tags: structural-analysis, automotive-engineering

For those of you who are following the development of the Cybertruck, the latest modification is a size reduction of the body by 3%. Assuming this is dimensionally and not by volume, do you think this could make much difference in the strength / stiffness of the body if they use the same gauge stainless steel? 
I'm expecting a more rigid body.

Looking forward to your comments. :)

Comment: But why did you not apply the answer to your question here : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/35487/10902

Comment: My little brain is about to spontaneously combust just looking @ the conversation on the other thread! :D  Great discussion & I appreciate the responses, it just shows me how complex a seemingly simple concept is!  Thankyou. :)

Comment: That is why I gave you a simple example in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

The longer a beam is, the more flexible...

So, make it shorter and the reverse is true, but if they reduce the width and breadth as well then not so much.

Answer (score 0):

There are many factors gone into the design of a monocoque truck or car design.

One of the most important is to design strength geometry usually by building conical or  half cylindrical or other (surface muscle) geometry absorbing load and shock and distributing it at a lower intensity to the rest of the frame.

Small reduction in size could be just a byproduct of modifying the design.

Another important factor in design of monocoque cars or trucks is to incorporate sacrifice high energy absorbing catastrophic crash assemblies to let the structure collapse , deforming excessively damping a lat of kinetic energy, while providing a safety cage for driver and passengers.